# How to access the data outside the closure in Swift without using tableView.reloadData()?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using an UIViewController and fetching images from firebaseUI and want to animate it. But I can't get the Idea how to do it. Please do help me. 
How to achieve it without using tableViewController?

```
func getImage()
        {
           var Images = [String]()
            Images = ModelManager.getInstance().getImages(imageName)


            let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
            let storageRef = storage.child("images")

            for x in Images{


                let path = storageRef.child("\(x).jpg")         
                path.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }
                    else{
                            self.imageList += [UIImage(data: data!)!]
                    }
                }

            }


            myImageView.animationImages = imageList
            myImageView.animationDuration = 2
            myImageView.startAnimating()
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive your requirement as below.

```
 func getImage()
        {
            var Images = [String]()
            Images = ModelManager.getInstance().getImages(imageName)

            let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
            let storageRef = storage.child("images")

            for x in Images{
                let path = storageRef.child("\(x).jpg")
                path.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        print(error)
                        return
                    }else{
                        self.imageList += [UIImage(data: data!)!]
                    }

                    if x = Images.last {
                        myImageView.animationImages = imageList
                        myImageView.animationDuration = 2
                        myImageView.startAnimating()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Hitesh Surani, I will apply the solution and let you know about the output

Comment: Yeah i upvoted  it but as i have less than 15 reputations its not getting registered